# how to using single-<post-type>.php

Tags: wordpress

i create single-xxx.php and single-yyy.php but i dont crate single.php is that wrong?

i create single-xxx.php and single-yyy.php because i have different template with 2 category post. let's call it xxx category and yyy category.i am using in different page too. index.php for xxx.php and event.php for yyy.php. but it doesn't work , any idea?

Thanks in advance for any help, and I'm really sorry if this has been asked before.

reference to http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solve i get the solution from http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/12/06/creating-single-post-templates-in-wordpress

thanks